# SQL group table by user with custom column on same row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables

**PATIENT**:

```
patientid name   comment  result
--------------------------------
1         davis  test     p
2         brown  test     p
3         mike   test     p
```

**PHONE TYPE**:

```
phone_id patient_id phone_type 
-------------------------------
3324       1          1 
3325       1          4
5467       2          1
```

**PHONE DETAILS**:

```
phone_id  number
-----------------------
3324      8253322
3325      180040204
5467      5674543
```

The goal is to add a column on the select statement based on the value of phone type (1 = phone, 4 = fax) and to group the column so that the phone and
fax are on the same line, not alternating.

Desired result:

```
name   phone      fax         comment result
---------------------------------------------
davis  8253322    180040204   test       p
brown  5674543    null        test       p
mike   null       null        test       p
```

I have this so far

```
select 
    a.name, a.comment, a.result,
    (CASE WHEN (b.phone_type = 1) THEN c.number ELSE NULL END) AS Phone
    (CASE WHEN (b.phone_type = 4) THEN c.number ELSE NULL END) AS Fax
```

The problem with this is that it doesn't group the values by the user.

```
    name   phone      fax         comment result
    -----------------------------------------------
    davis  8253322    null        test       p
    davis  null       180040204   test       p
    mike   null       null        test       p
```

Comment: if we assume a name can not have more than 1 of each then you just need to wrap the case in max statements and group by the name, comment and result.  If a name can have more than 1 phone and fax how do you want them to be related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we can assume 1 phone/fax per name.

```
select a.name
     , a.comment
     , a.result
     , max(CASE WHEN (b.phone_type = 1) THEN c.number ELSE NULL END) AS Phone
     , max((CASE WHEN (b.phone_type = 4) THEN c.number ELSE NULL END) AS Fax
FROM...
GROUP BY a.name
     , a.comment
     , a.result
```

If not... then break phone and fax into two data sets based the type and generate row number for each set. Then use a full outer join on patentId and that row number.

```
With Phone as (SELECT phone_id, patient_id, phone_type, PD.Number, row_number() over (partition by Patient_ID order by PD.Number) as RN

           FROM Phone_type PT
           INNER JOIN Phone_Details PD
              ON PT.Phone_ID = PD.Phone_ID
           WHERE Phone_Type = 1),
  Fax as (SELECT phone_id, patient_id, phone_type, PD.Number, row_number() over (partition by Patient_ID order by PD.Number) as RN
           FROM Phone_type PT
           INNER JOIN Phone_Details PD
              ON PT.Phone_ID = PD.Phone_ID
           WHERE Phone_Type = 1)
SELECT *
FROM PHONE P
FULL OUTER JOIN FAX F
 on P.Patent_Id =F.PatentID
and P.RN=F.RN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an aggregation function if you are sure you will only ever have one value at most for phone or fax.

```
select a.name, a.comment, a.result,
       Min((CASE WHEN (b.phone_type = 1) THEN c.number ELSE NULL END) AS Phone,
Min((CASE WHEN (b.phone_type = 4) THEN c.number ELSE NULL END)) AS Fax
FROM (...)
GROUP BY a.name, a.comment, a.result
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following SQL statement

```
WITH patient_phone AS (
SELECT a.name,
       a.comment,
       a.result,
       (CASE WHEN (b.phone_type = 1) THEN c.number ELSE NULL END) AS Phone,
       (CASE WHEN (b.phone_type = 4) THEN c.number ELSE NULL END) AS Fax
  FROM patient a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN phone_type b
    ON a.patient_id = b.patient_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN phone_details c
    ON b.phone_id = c.phone_id
 GROUP BY a.name,
          a.comment,
          a.result,
          b.phone_type,
          c.number
) 

SELECT name,       
       MAX(phone) phone,
       MAX(fax) fax,
       comment,
       result
  FROM patient_phone
 GROUP BY name,
          comment,
          result
```

Result

```
name    phone   fax         comment result
brown   5674543 NULL        test    p
davis   8253322 180040204   test    p
mike    NULL    NULL        test    p
```